# Use Git command to list "remote repo" files in specific directory

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to be able to list the files under a remote Git repo's specific directory. Did lots of Googling but no luck.

I am trying to use Jenkins to perform some specific "integration tests", but not all of them. I don't want to run all tests because it's very time consuming (due to dumb company politic reasons).

I wish to list the "test group files" remotely in advance (ie. before I kick off Jenkins build), so I can only execute the tests I want to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list the files in a particular commit of a **local** repo, from the root directory of that repo, as follows:

For a list of files that changed in a commit:

```sh
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r <hash/branch/tag> <file pattern>
```

For a list of all files present in the file-tree (with or without a change) at a given commit:

```sh
git ls-tree --name-only -r <hash/branch/tag> <file pattern>
```

So, if you already have a clone of the repo, you should be able to script one of the above to return a list of any pattern of files in the local repo, for any commit, branch, or tag.

For example, to get all files in the file-tree for the remote `origin/master` branch commit, for all files in the `myfolder` directory with a `*.jpg` pattern match, use:

```sh
git ls-tree --name-only -r origin/master myfolder/*.jpg
```

You can then use the resulting list however needed via additional scripting.

Comment: thanks. the diff-tree only shows the modified files instead of showing all files under the directory. Is this your original intention?